# Search the similarity of 2 strings in java using part of word matching, not cosine similarity

Tags: java, regex, split

Hi I want to compare 2 strings by part of the words appear in other string. 
for example:
I have 4 strings:

```
A) "white snow ball"
B) "super exciting"
C) "white image superdupercold"
D) "cold"
```

and user search by this string "`super cold white snow`"
the result should be return in this order:

```
C, A, D, B
```

because B has only one match "super" in total 2 words (similarity = 50%) while D has one match "cold" in total 1 word (similarity = 100%). A has 2 matches "white" and "snow" and C has 3 matches
However, if I use cosine similarity, it will rank differently:
[image: results of cosine similarity]

Another example: if user search by this string "super", then the result should be return in this order:
B, C

I think it could be solved by something from regex and string split. Is there any nice and clean way to write it in java ?

Comment: What did you try so far? Share with us your code please.

Comment: I only tried cosine similarity and it doesn't show the result I expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each search string, split it into words using `haystack.split("\\s+")` (`\\s+` is regexp-ese for 'the strings are separated by whitespace').

Then, to obtain a 'score' you need 2 numbers: How many words matched, and how many words there are total. You sort descending on first, and ascending on last, which gets you the behaviour you seem to want.

```
String[] needle = "super cold white snow".split("\\s+");
String[] haystack = "white image superdupercold".split("\\s+");
int matchedWords = 0, totalWords = haystack.length;
for (String n : needle) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (String hay : haystack) {
        if (hay.contains(n)) {
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (found) matchedWords++;
}
```

For each needle, you now end up with 2 scores: matchedWords, and totalWords.

For any 2 given such scorepairs, the winner is the one with the higher matchedWords; totalWords serves as tiebreaker, and it works in reverse (the lower totalWords wins).

There are various ways to try to represent this. One easy trick is to 'encode' all this into a single long value:

```
private static final long MULTIPLIER = 0x100000000L;
long score = MULTIPLIER * matchedWords + (Integer.MAX_VALUE - totalWords);
```

now the higher scoring needle is the best answer.

The other option is to make a class representing the needle along with the two score numbers, put all results in a list, and then sort the list:

```
@Value
class Result { String needle; int words, total; }

list.sort(
    Comparator.comparing(Result::getWords).reversed().
    thenComparing(Comparator.comparing(Result::getTotal));

list.stream().map(Result::getNeedle).forEach(System.out::println);
```

NB: If the aim is to do this very efficiently, so you can process a needle through a few hundred thousand haystacks in a fast manner, the answer lies in wordsearch solutions such as postgres tsvectors or libraries like [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/).

Types used in these snippets:

- lombok's [`@Value`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Value)
- `java.util.Comparator`

Comment: will this take into accout word in 'needle' appear in part of the word in 'haystack' ? e.g. 'super' and 'cold' only match part of 'superdupercold' but we still need to count them in ?

Comment: Yes, it will. Try it.

Comment: Thank you very much, it work as expected! Excellent answer, tks for fast and prompt !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your strings stored in an array or a list (I've puted them in a `String[]` array), and further assuming you want to exclude strings with no match from your result as your second example indicates, something like below should work:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String search = "super cold white snow";
        for(String s: getOrderdResults(search)){
            System.out.println(s);
        }        
    }

    public static String[] getOrderdResults(String search){
        String[] myStrings = {"white snow ball", "super exciting", "white image superdupercold", "cold"};

        String[] filterd =  Arrays.stream(myStrings).filter(s ->isThereAnyMatch(s,search)).toArray(String[]::new);

        Comparator<String> byQuota = (s1,s2)->Double.compare(getMatchQuota(s2, search), getMatchQuota(s1, search));
        Comparator<String> byCount = (s1,s2)->Long.compare(getMatchCount(s2, search), getMatchCount(s1, search));

        return Arrays.stream(filterd)
                .sorted(byCount.thenComparing(byQuota))
                .toArray(String[]::new);
    }

    public static boolean isThereAnyMatch(String myString, String search){
        return Arrays.stream(search.split("\\s+")).anyMatch(s -> myString.contains(s));
    }

    public static long getMatchCount(String myString, String search){
        return Arrays.stream(search.split("\\s+")).filter(s -> myString.contains(s)).count();
    }

    public static double getMatchQuota(String myString, String search){
        return (double)getMatchCount(myString,search) / myString.split("\\s+").length;
    }
}
```

Comment: tk you, I have up-voted. But can choose only one, so I have to choose the earlier. Tks.